# Can't simulate 64-bit operating systems on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

## My solution

I tried to use VirtualBox to simulate [Windows 10 Technical Preview](http://preview.windows.com), but experienced problems (see below).
My solution was to use Hyper-V (as answered in [this](https://superuser.com/a/820804/375229) comment).
**How to access Hyper-V:** Type in the Start Menu search `Hyper-V Manager`.

## My problem

I'm using Windows 8.1 Pro x64 build 9600.
My goal is to simulate Windows 10 Technical Preview x64 on VirtualBox.
I downloaded VirtualBox 4.3.16 from [its official download page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).
This is my system information:
[image]
Steps i've tried:

1. I enabled virtualization: 
   [image]
2. I executed command in CMD: `"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" modifyvm "Windows 10" --longmode on`
3. I enabled Hyper-V feature:
   [image]
4. I also tried to use a 32-bit ISO of Windows 10 Technical Preview.
   If the status of Hyper-V is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh67S.png) or [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvpQq.png), I get the following error when I start simulating Windows 10 Technical Preview:
   [image]
   However, if I [enable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmEvZ.png) Hyper-V, I get the following error:
   [image]
   If I hit Continue, the following error comes:
   [image]

I still cannot use 64-bit operating systems: [image]

Comment: Windows 10 does not work on VirtualBox anyway (tried it myself). Use VmWare Player for it.

Comment: The [following video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzKpbLnCmNg) actually proofs that it does.

Comment: @kinokijuf It does work on VirtualBox, I'm using it right now.

Comment: @kinokijuf I'm running Win10 64-bit in VirtualBox (Win 8.1 64-bit host) it works.  Not sure why OP doesn't have 64-bit options though...

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 How did you enable 64-bit on VirtualBox?

Comment: I didn't, they are just available... Do you have the Hyper-V Windows feature installed by any chance?

Comment: @Brad Dunno, maybe it’s my graphic card. [I described my problems here](http://www.betaarchive.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=62&t=32560)

Comment: That's super wierd. Also, you're going to want to pick windows 8 *not* other as your version. It fails horribly with 'other'. I've gotten it working on virtualbox *and* KVM with no issues so far.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I did pick Windows 8.1. The picture in my main post describes that I cannot pick a 64-bit OS at all.

Comment: Hyper-V should not be used with VirtualBox, they are incompatible and more to the point they do the same thing. Have you considered trying to run your Windows 10 preview on Hyper-V instead of VirtualBox?

Comment: @Aron How do I do this?

Comment: Go to the start menu. Search for `Hyper-V Manager`. New. Virtual Machine.

Comment: @avi12 I've converted my comment to a full answer...upvote and accept as necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By installing Hyper-V on step 3, the OP inadvertently installed a bare-metal hypervisor onto the machine. For hardware virtualization to work, the hypervisor is required to take hold of a specific feature on the CPU, either Intel VT-x or AMD-V. Only one hypervisor can control this feature at a time. In addition, a bare-metal hypervisor is in control of this feature every time the machine starts up.

For this reason you may not run more than one of the following at one time (with all feature, or at all)

- Hyper-V*
- Parallels Workstation
- QEMU
- VirtualBox
- Virtual PC
- VMware ESXi*
- VMware Workstation
- VMware Workstation Player
- Windows Defender Application Guard*
- Any other hypervisor that uses hardware virtualization

Items marked with * are bare-metal hypervisors.

The solution is to either uninstall Hyper-V or use Hyper-V instead of VirtualBox.

I would advise you to do the last option, as Hyper-V will be much better tested with Windows 10 preview than VirtualBox will have been.

Comment: I'm able to simulate Windows 10 Tech Preview on Hyper-V. The only problem is, there is no internet connection.

Comment: You need to setup your Hyper-V Virtual Switch. Attach the virtual switch to your Real network card. Then create a virtual network card on your VM, which is also attached to the virtual switch...google a tutorial.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/480e6460-17c8-4b44-9ca1-d7f185ad8601/hyperv-virtual-switch-windows-8?forum=W8ITProPreRel) question to find all required settings (Leonid Ganeline's answer solved the problem).