# Why is VirtualBox only showing 32-bit?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, 64-bit

My system runs Windows 10 on a 64-bit system, has hyper-v turned off, as well as virtualization and the VT-d feature enabled in BIOS. Despite this, VB is only showing the 32-bit versions.

I run the 6.0.6 version of VB

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling VB, turning on and turning off hyper-v as well as virtualization and the VT-d feature.

Has any one experienced this before? Or have any idea what to do to fix this issue?

Comment: Do you have Intel HAXM installed? Is Windows Defender Device Guard activated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does virtualbox only have 32-bit option, no 64-bit option on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/866962/why-does-virtualbox-only-have-32-bit-option-no-64-bit-option-on-windows-7)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [VirtualBox on Windows 10 64bit doesn't have a 64bit option](https://superuser.com/questions/1211629/virtualbox-on-windows-10-64bit-doesnt-have-a-64bit-option/1366359#1366359)

Comment: There is only a single Windows VirtualBox executable that can be downloaded.  It does not matter if VirtualBox itself is 32-bit or 64-bit, due to the fact you can run a 64-bit operating system within a VM, on a 32-bit host provided you have compatiable hardware.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of: [Can't simulate 64-bit operating systems on VirtualBox](https://superuser.com/questions/820735/cant-simulate-64-bit-operating-systems-on-virtualbox?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

I recently installed Virtual Box 6 and it's installed in "C:\Program Files" on Windows 10 Professional 64-bit which suggests it's 64-bit software.  I'm not sure if you're referring to the website not showing you the correct version?  The version I downloaded came from here:

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Where I clicked on the "Windows hosts" link.  This downloaded a file named:

VirtualBox-6.0.4-128413-Win.exe

(which doesn't appear to contain a CPU architecture in the name)

[image]

I assume you have 64-bit hardware and a 64-bit OS?  Have you been able to install other 64-bit software?

Comment: In my case, I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 64 bit guest running on Virtual Box, but I think he's referring to the Virtual Box software itself, but we'll have to see what he says.

Comment: VirtualBox on Windows only supports one architecture x86, it does not matter if VirtualBox is a 32-bit or 64-bit process, the author's problem is connected to virtualization technology (VT-x) not being available to VirtualBox.  The author indicated, in their question, they were running a 64-bit version of Windows 10.  All Intel/AMD x86 processors sold today are 64-bit.  Additionally, all Intel/AMD 64-bit processors are based on the x86 architecture.  VT-d being enabled or disabled isn't important.

Comment: @Ramhound it's not clear since his statement "VB is only showing the 32-bit versions" is not clear.

Comment: @BrandonHawbaker - I must disagree.  I know what the author's problem is exactly, based on the fact this exact same problem, has been asked hundreds of times.  There is only two reasons VitualBox would not display the option for a 64-bit operating system, the hardware does not support it (which isn't the case), and VT-x is being used by a system process.

Comment: @Ramhound I agree with you he probably mean it is only showing 32-bit guest OSs.. Any idea what kind of system (service?) typically uses/might use VT-x and prevents virtualbox from using it?

Comment: @barlop - Core Isolation and/of Hyper-V and/or security software.  All reasons are handled by the numerous duplicates